# How can I return a 302 HTTP response in JSP?

Tags: javascript, http, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I need to submit a form using JavaScript. The problem is my JavaScript POST request gets an “OK — 200” response. In order to make it 302 I think I need to use `response.sendredirect` in my <del>JavaScript</del> JSP function. Can any body tell me how to use it? With example code.

Comment: You can only use it in server end, can you please elaborate a question a bit more

Comment: ya i know i can use it in  server side.. but jus wanted to know is there any other way to avoid 200 OK problem in post method ..?

Comment: @Sachin: you can *only* use it on the server side. You seem a bit confused about HTTP.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the actual issue, 200 OK means success, so whats the problem ?

Comment: It does not prevent caching of confidential
information. Upon submitting a form, if click  refresh button  it re sends the parameter to server . i do not want it to send to server again.

Comment: @Jigar: ideally when submitting a form, you want it to return a 302 “Found” redirect (*ideally* ideally you’d go with a 303 “See Other”, but let’s stick to the old ways for now). This causes the browser to issue a GET request to the URL you’re redirecting to, which is nice because if the use then refreshes the page, they don’t get a browser message saying “Are you sure you want to submit the form again?”

Comment: @Paul yes it seems [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: @Jigar: ooh, good link, that’s the one. Also the caching stuff that @Sachin said I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won’t use `response.sendredirect` in your JavaScript, there’s no such thing. If you’re submitting a form using JavaScript, then JavaScript is your HTTP client. It sends the POST request, with the form data, to whichever server you’re submitting to.

The server then sends the HTTP response back to your JavaScript. It’s currently sending 200, but you’re looking for it to return a 302 redirect instead. You’d use `response.sendredirect` on the server to do that — it’s not part of your JavaScript. There’s also no way to specify what sort of response you want in HTTP. It’s entirely up to the server.

So, judging by your tags, you’ll want to use `response.sendredirect` in your JSP code on the server. I’m afraid I’m not familiar with JSP, so I can’t really help there. It might help other answerers if you post some of your server-side code though — at the moment we’ve got no idea what’s going on there.